# Lots of error logs 404 Errors from simplesite.com

Tags: apache, http-status-code-404, referrer

I am seeing a disturbing amount of 404 errors generating from simplesite.com. Looking for WordPress wp-content & wp-admin, public_html pages, cgi-bin pages, and .well-known folder files. Some are pretty bogus names like ffAA531.php in the cgi-bin folder? Has anyone encountered these and know what might be the cause? for the first time literally ever Google was no help. See example

[Fri Mar 25 08:26:04.756798 2022] [:error] [pid 110041:tid 139831157606144] [client 198.71.235.35:0] File does not exist: /home2/craftkings/public_html/.well-known/991176.php, referer: http://simplesite.com

Comment: Every site exposed to the Internet will be scanned like crazy.  Tools exist that will send requests to your site with millions of scripts, pages, links, ... just hoping to find something they can use and exploit.  Your logs can be full of those.  If you see a huge number of requests from the same referrer you can block his requests in Apache (but you will still see the logs), or using an IDS in front.

Comment: Appreciate that. I had to figure as much.